# Where is the panel to change parameters for gears created using the Extra add-on?

Tags: mesh

Gear is added but I can't find the the panel that lets you change number of teeth, diameter etc. Sorry for being dumb. Can sb guide a dummy?

Comment: Which addon are you using? If you have loaded the one called "Add Mesh: Extra Objects", then a gear is available, and I can change its starting parameters just fine. As soon as it's created, the standard options box appears in the bottom left of the 3D viewport. Just expand it and change the number of teeth or whatever.

Comment: Hi R-800, thx for your help. It was minimised as you say, stupid me. I am trying to find it on the right panels. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for R-800. It was minimised on the bottom left. It is not on the right as i thought it would be.